# regex to match age written in textual format

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the age of a person from a sentence; this is a bit simplified, but it's all for a research project. I know that in the sentence the age is always preceded by either a colon followed by 0 or more spaces, or a colon, spaces, a few words, and some spaces (example: "character: a lovely eighty year old grandma", I want a regex that will allow me to extract 'eighty' from one of the groups). I am using python's 're' library and my code hangs on this example (code and example below):

```
regex_age_string = r'([:]*[ ]*)?((([a-z]*)([ -]*))+)([ -]+)(year)'
regex_age_string = re.compile(regex_age_string, re.DOTALL)
sentence = 'history:   four year-old boy was really sad when he found 
out the toy was broken'
age_extract_string = re.search(regex_age_string, sentence)
print(age_extract_string.group())
print(age_extract_string.group(2))
```

However, the  works when I shorten the sentence by cutting out a few of the tail words. I read up about regex searches hanging because of catastrophic backtracking but I am not sure how that applies here/how to fix it.

Comment: is your age always followed by `year`?

Comment: The reason is as usual: catastrophic backtracking. Maybe all you need is to extract any text between `:` and `year`? Try [`:\s*(.*?)\s*year`](https://regex101.com/r/X60U23/1/). Or if you only want to limit the capture to letters, `-` and spaces, [`:\s*([a-z\s-]*?)\s*year`](https://regex101.com/r/X60U23/2).

Comment: can you give more examples? age can be multiple words? (e.g twenty one)

Comment: Age can be multiple words, so I would like this to capture the ages in the cases where I have "twenty one" or "twenty-one-years-old" or "twenty-one years old".

Comment: So this works it seems `'r':\s*([a-z\s-]*?)\s*[-]*year'` . Can someone explain what the catastrophic backtracking was in my case? I understand the concept at a high level but understanding what exactly in my example was problematic would be super helpful for learning!

Comment: you need to narrow your boundary conditions. imagine two sentences: "history: is four years old" and "history: twenty four years old". It seems difficult for a regex to discern between "is" and "twenty" without further logic. Which one is a number? They have the same context. Personally I would write some logic for this edge cases, something like `check if word is in (set of multiples of ten)` and apply it to the word preceding "four" in this example

Comment: Hi Maria, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129993/3832970). The point is that you have a sequence of optional subpatterns in a `+`-quantified group inside a pattern. That almost always causes hang-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regex causes slowdown is [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). It is caused by a sequence of optional patterns inside a quantified group - `(([a-z]*)([ -]*))+`.

You may actually match any letters, spaces or hyphens from a `:` till `year`:

```
r':\s*([a-z\s-]*?)\s*-*year'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X60U23/3).

**Details**

- `:` - a `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespacves
- `([a-z\s-]*?)` - Group 1: 0+ lowercase ASCII letters, whitespaces or hyphens
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `-*` - 0+ `-` chars
- `year` - a substring.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! And kudos for the *incredibly* quick reply.

Comment: @Maria Glad it did. If you haven't upvoted the answer, please do (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you can use the following regex to fetch ages (case insensitive of people between **0-999** years old)

```
(?i)\b(?:zero|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty)\b(?=\s*year)|\b(?:(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)? hundred(?:\sand)?\s)?(?:(?:twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)[\s-]?)?\b(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)?(?=\syear)
```

It worked the following sentences:

```
history:   Zero year-old baby
history:   FOUR year-old boy was really sad when he found 
out the toy was broken
character: a lovely eighty-three year old grandma
test: a nice eighty year-old father
character: a lovely eighty years old grandma
character: a lovely ninety-nine year old grandma
research: a great eight year-old brother
character: a lovely one hundred ninety-nine year old increadible grandma
character: a lovely one hundred and ninety-nine year old really increadible grandma
character: a lovely one hundred one year old super increadible grandma
character: a lovely nine hundred and ninety-nine year old super super increadible grandma
character: a lovely nine hundred ninety nine year old super super increadible grandma
```

Feel free to adapt it to go to **thousands** and **millions** year old grandma

***[DEMO on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VCFYYp/1/)***